# What to use as server for my .Net Core 6 application on my local machine?

Tags: c#, server, asp.net, apache

I am building an app using ASP.NET Core & C# on my local machine and need recommendations to what should be my server to host my app. This is a personal project and so far the idea is a light weight application. I am new to doing this from scratch all by myself so any recommendations are appreciated. Thank you all. Cheers!

I have used IIS at work previously but I am looking for a better and faster service to use instead. Again, I am not well version in this corner. I saw online that Kestrel or Apache could be some options but wanted to get more opinions on this.